# Coloque una palabra en el medio si 2 secuencias de caracteres están separadas por 2 o más palabras dentro de una cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, str-replace, replace

```py
import re

def person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, number_of_people_involved = "singular"):

    if   (number_of_people_involved == "singular"): assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(SINGULAR_PERS)", "le"
    elif (number_of_people_involved == "plural"):   assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(PLURAL_PERS)", "les"

    n_or_more_words = r""
    input_text = re.sub(r"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))\s*(" + n_or_more_words + r")\s*(" + personal_pronoun + r")\s*\(\(VERB\)", 
                        lambda m: (f"{m[1]} {m[2]} " + assumed_subject_of_sentence + " {m[3]} ((VERB)"),
                        input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
    return input_text


#input string example:
input_text = "le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego le ((VERB)ayudo)"

input_text = person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, "singular")
print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

¿Cómo hago para que este programa agregue `"(SINGULAR_PERS)"` delante de `"le"`, si y solo si, no hay una secuencia `"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*) )+\))"` dos o más palabras antes de la última aparición de la cadena `"le"` (lo mismo si nunca hay una secuencia `"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s* )+\))` antes de `"le"`, ya que se interpreta que hay no menos de 2 palabras de por medio, si nunca apareció la primera condición)?

Debería asignar a la variable `n_or_more_words` un patrón de expresión regular que indique que se requieren al menos 2 o más palabras (una palabra se entiende como una secuencia de caracteres sin espacios entre `\w+` ) entre la última aparición de un secuencia `"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))"` y un `"le"`

Entonces, después de realizar el reemplazo, debería obtener esta string por output:

```
"(SINGULAR_PERS) le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego (SINGULAR_PERS) le ((VERB)ayudo),
```

---

**EDIT**

Intento de código de la función:

```py
def person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, number_of_people_involved="singular"):

    if number_of_people_involved == "singular":
        assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(SINGULAR_PERS)", "le"
    elif number_of_people_involved == "plural":
        assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(PLURAL_PERS)", "les"

    n_or_more_words = r"\w+\s+\w+\s*"
    input_text = re.sub(r"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))\s*(" + n_or_more_words + r")(" + personal_pronoun + r")\s*\(\(VERB\)",
                        lambda m: (f"{m[1]} {m[2]} " + assumed_subject_of_sentence + f" {m[3]} ((VERB)"),
                        input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return input_text
```

Esta funcion por algun motivo no logra modificar la string

Comment: A estas alturas está claro que las expresiones regulares no te llevaran a destino.

Comment: @CandidMoe Es cierto si esta complicado, pero con esta regex pude solucionar la parte que involucra agregar si hay mas de 2 palabras `\w` en medio `input_text = re.sub(r"\(\(PERS\)((?:\w\s*)+)\)(\s*((?!" + personal_pronoun + ")\w+\s+){2,})(" + personal_pronoun + ")", lambda m: (f"((PERS){m[1]}) {m[2]} " + assumed_subject_of_sentence + " " + personal_pronoun), input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)` , lo que falta mejorar es agregar en esa o en una segunda regex la capacidad de si no hay ningún `"((PERS) )"` delante del primer `"le"` entonces agregar `"(SINGULAR_PERS)"` delante de ese primer `"le"`